# Laravel 5.1 - phpunit - ErrorException: Undefined property: ExampleTest::$baseUrl

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1

I have the default setup. My composer.json has this:

```
"require-dev": {
  "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
  "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
  "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
```

When i run phpunit, i get the following error: **I'm not sure why?**

PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

```
E

Time: 272 ms, Memory: 13.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
ErrorException: Undefined property: ExampleTest::$baseUrl
```

My ExampleTest.php contains the following code

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

I'm very new to testing. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the info from @tk. All you have to do is add a protected property in the parent class **TestCase**

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://yoursite.dev';
```

It solved the issue